# if $\sup_{x\in A}\left\Vert (D^{2}f)_{x}\right\Vert =M $ then exists $r>0$ such that $f|_{B_{r}\left(x_{0}\right)}$ is injective

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ open set, and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k $ is twice differentiable such that $$\sup_{x\in A}\left\Vert (D^{2}f)_{x}\right\Vert =M < \infty$$ and exists $x_0 \in A$ such that $\det\left(Df_{x_{0}}\right)\neq0$, find $r>0$ for which $f|_{B_{r}\left(x_{0}\right)}$ is injective.

I believe that the mean value theorem is needed here, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use it in this case.

Comment: Inverse function theorem?

Comment: This is a rather peculiar setup for a question, are you sure you have the wording correct?

Comment: Pretty sure it's all correct.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect that I can see, but if it an application of the inverse function theorem then there are some superfluous hypotheses.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I'm actually needed to find such $r$.

Comment: Do you mean you want an explicit $r$, possibly in terms of $M$?

Comment: There must be more context to the problem.